# How can I mock/create ReqData for testing an actix web request handler?

Tags: testing, rust, mocking, middleware, actix-web

I am trying to unit-test a request handler that uses middleware to pass data into it. Before implementing the middleware tests were fairly straightforward, I could use `web::Data::new(data)` to pass test data into the handler. However, now that the data is wrapped in `web::ReqData` I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass in data for testing.

example:

```rust
pub async fn handler(
  some_data: web::Data<SomeDataType>,
  req_data: web::ReqData<ReqestDataType>
) -> HttpResponse {
  // some code
}

#[actix_rt::test]
async fn test_fn() {
  let resp = handler(
    web::Data::new(someData),
    // what can I put here?
  ).await;
  assert_eq!(resp.status(), status_code::OKAY);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Request-local data is arbitrary data attached to an individual request, usually by middleware. It can be set via extensions_mut on HttpRequest or ServiceRequest"

`ReqData<T>` can be extracted from the HttpRequest using `extract` method of `ReqData<T>`.
[Refer](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/web/struct.ReqData.html)

How to create test HttpRequest is documented [here](https://docs.rs/actix-web/4.4.0/actix_web/test/struct.TestRequest.html)

With this information we create a test HttpRequest then set the ReqData using the `extensions_mut` method, then extract it using `ReqData::extract` method.

**Example**:

```html
use actix_web::{HttpResponse, web};

#[derive(Debug, Clone, serde::Deserialize, serde::Serialize)]
pub struct User {
    id: u32,
    name: String,
}

pub async fn handler(
  some_data: web::Data<String>,
  req_data: web::ReqData<User>
) -> HttpResponse {
  // some code
  println!("{:?}", some_data);
  println!("{:?}", req_data);
  HttpResponse::Ok().finish()
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {

    use actix_web::{test, FromRequest, HttpMessage, web::ReqData};

    use super::*;
    #[actix_rt::test]
    async fn test_fn() {
    let http_request = test::TestRequest::default().to_http_request();
    http_request.extensions_mut().insert(User{id: 1, name: "User1".to_string()});
    let _ = handler(
        web::Data::new("Dummy data".to_string()),
        ReqData::extract(&http_request).await.unwrap()
    ).await;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make sure that your answer is useful without the linked resources. If necessary quote the relevant parts here, preferably you'd provide a short example of how to apply the linked resources.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Completed the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will try this out. Although what a workaround! 

Comment: I ended up creating a utility function based on your answer. Thanks again!